# Redirect Index.html page based on local month and day

Tags: javascript

My website "skytamer.com" currently has 366 verions of the index.html page that I manually load each evening.  The 366 versions are stored in the in the following directory:

www.skytamer.com/date/0101.html.

The 366 files, are denoted as i.e, 0101.html (January 1), 0601.html (June 1) etc., one for each day of the year.

I need a script that will automatically redirect the index.html page based on the computer's timestamp local month and day.

Example, the Earth keeps turning and 6 June comes around.  The "index.html" page should then load "www.skytamer.com/date/0601.html" as the new "index.html" page.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The script:

```
function getPageToday() {
var today = new Date();
var day = String(today.getDate());
var month = String(today.getMonth() + 1);
if (day.length === 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
}
if (month.length === 1) {
    month = '0' + month;
}
var page = month + day + '.html';
return page;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">` combined with a simple script that checks the date.

Keep in mind that timezones exist, so you might want grab the time from the server if you have server side scripting available.

Comment: How does grabbing server time serve the right file for end user?

Comment: You need to know the time, JavaScript time is based on the user's CPU clock, so you can't trust it. If you set the date in your OS to 1 jan 1930, JavaScript will think it's 1 jan 1930. You control the server time, so you know you can reasonably trust it. It's a minor issue, but it's good to keep in mind when dealing with dates.

Comment: Well add a double check, javascript + server side, at any given time user date should be +/-1day of the server date

Comment: What I mean is, if you're in Pacific timezone and the user is in say, Koala Lumpur, how does serving a page based on the server's time work to serve the correct file for the end user?  @Ani and if they differ, which do you refer to?  Do you trust the +/- 1 day client-reported time or defer to server time?

Comment: That depends what _'the correct time'_ is. If you operate a webshop that has discounts on specific dates, I'm pretty sure you're gonna use the server-time.